# What is the term describing a word using in the definition of another word?

Tags: terminology, lexical-relations

From [definiens - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/definiens):

> (semantics) The word or phrase that defines the definiendum in a definition.
>   In the defining statement “A lake is a large, landlocked, naturally occurring stretch of water”, “large, landlocked, naturally occurring stretch of water” is the definiens.

But what is the term to describe “large", "landlocked", "naturally", etc? *Definiens* also? All I know that if we have a definition "An elephant is an animal", then *animal* is a [hypernym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy) of *elephant*.

<sup>Also: [Definition - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definition)</sup>

Comment: You're missing a word or two in the title... Also I'd recommend using the word "term" to make it less confusing.

Comment: is this better?

Comment: I think it's good now - a term is a sub category of words, and neither the word being defined or those used in its definition have to be terms, in the sense of linguistic jargon.

Comment: Those are all part of the definiens, yes. Depending on what analysis you're doing, you could also call them qualifiers of "stretch of water" or adjective phrases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **keyword** can be used if the context is clear that it doesn't refer to the [linguistic sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyword_(linguistics)).